# Subir imagenes con AJAX, Jquery Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola amigos de stackoverflow tengo un error en este codigo y busco un poco de su ayuda para solucionar este problema

**Explicación:**
Este es un pequeño script para subir archivos el problema esta en que subo los mismos archivos multiple veses incruso si selecion otras imagenes con el input.
como puedo hacer que no pase eso, porque ya intente vaciar el input pero me da error al cargar nuvas imagenes.

[image]

Codigo .PHP necesario
https://jsfiddle.net/vaL64odw/

Comment: Amigo tu explicación tiene muchos errores tipográficos, ¿podrías modificarlas para que la pregunta a tu error sea lo más clara posible?

Comment: Bueno uno de los problemas es que solo obtienes el primer archivo y por eso subes solo el primer archivo aunque te aparezcan los nombres de los demas el problema esta en esta linea **var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0]**